# Error Scrapy - Unhandled error in Deferred:

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted

I want to run an old crawler I created 2 years ago build with Scrapy but I got an error that stop everyting. I try multiple thing but nothing change.

Can someone help me to fix this issue ?

Thank you in advance.

Error when I start the crawler : `Unhandled error in Deferred:`

**My Spider :**

```
from __future__ import division
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from dirbot.settings import *
from scrapy import signals
import time
import tldextract, json, pika, os, signal

class HttpbinSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "expired_one"
    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), canonicalize=False), callback='parse_items', follow=True),)

    blacklist = [...]

    domains = ['http://www.website.com']

    allowed_suffix = [...]

    def __init__(self, domains=None, **kwargs):

        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue='expired', passive=False, durable=True, auto_delete=False)
        self.channel.confirm_delivery()
        #self.start_urls = json.loads(domains)
        self.start_urls = ['http://www.website.com']
        domain = json.loads(domains)
        ext = tldextract.extract(domain[0])
        self.allowed_domains = []
        self.allowed_domains.append(ext.registered_domain)

        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        super(HttpbinSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse_items(self, response):
        for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=self.allowed_domains, canonicalize=False).extract_links(response):
            ext = tldextract.extract(link.url)
            domain = ext.registered_domain
            if ext.suffix in self.allowed_suffix:
                if domain not in self.domains and domain not in self.blacklist:
                    self.connection.sleep(0.05)
                    self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='expired', body=domain,
                                               properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                                   delivery_mode=2,
                                               ))
                    self.domains.append(domain)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.connection.close()
        pid = os.getpid()
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

UPDATE TRACEBACK :

```
root@xxxx:/home/CrawlerNDD# scrapy crawl expired_one
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named x509'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.
Without the service_identity module, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
2018-08-12 15:14:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36)
2018-08-12 15:14:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 3.4.0.0, libxml2 2.9.1, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) - [GCC 4.9.2], pyOpenSSL 0.14 (OpenSSL 1.0.1t
3 May 2016), cryptography 0.6.1, Platform Linux-3.16.0-6-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-8.11
2018-08-12 15:14:55 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'dirbot.spiders', 'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 23554432, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['dirbot.spiders'], 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 128, 'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE': 0, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'dirbot.custom_filters.BLOOMDupeFilter', 'BOT_NAME': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36', 'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True, 'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 15, 'DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS': 'dirbot.items.Website', 'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue', 'DNS_TIMEOUT': 15, 'LOG_ENABLED': False, 'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'}
Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

Comment: Merely "Unhandled error in Deferred" doesn't make much sense. It should at least point to some line of code and be more specific. Please copy the whole traceback to the question.

Comment: Hello, I updated the post

Comment: I already installed service_identity but the first message still remain

Comment: is there no more text after the colon? Python normally points you to some line in the code and explains what kind of error occurred.

Comment: https://puu.sh/Bd0py/8000f885f3.png There is nothing afer the Unhandled error in Deferred:

Comment: well, this is weird...

Comment: I am assuming you don't see any further output because you are killing self explicitly immediately after the spider is done. Perhaps comment the SIGTERM lines and see how things play out.